# Not show hr through teeny_mce_buttons filter

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm building custom tinymce bar buttons for my wp theme, using wp_editor and teeny, but I have a problem. When I add hr and charmap, these buttons not appear in the tinymce bar.

This is the wp_editor configuration:

```
 $settings = array( 
                'textarea_name' => 'xor_options[' . $editor . ']',
                'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,del,ul,ol,li,close' ),
                'media_buttons' => true,
                'wpautop'   => false,
                'textarea_rows' => 5,
                'editor_height' => 200,
                'teeny' => true,
                'tinymce' => true
        );
 wp_editor( $xor_output, $xor_editor_id, $settings );
```

Now I'm using the filter for teeny buttons.

```
add_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', 'xor_editor_buttons', 10, 2 );
function xor_editor_buttons( $buttons, $editor_id ) {

    if( $editor_id != 'footer-editor' ) return $buttons;

    $buttons = array( 
        'undo',
        'redo',
        'formatselect',
        'bold', 
        'italic', 
        'underline', 
        'strikethrough',
        'blockquote',
        'bullist',
        'numlist',
        'outdent',
        'indent',
        'alignleft', 
        'alignright',
        'aligncenter', 
        'alignjustify',
        'link',
        'unlink',
        'hr', // not appears!
        'charmap', // not appears!
        'removeformat',
        'fullscreen'
        );

    return $buttons;
}
```

Where is the error in my code or this is a little bug? I'm using Wordpress 4.9. Thanks!

---

**SOLVED**

I set on false teeny. Then I set tinymce as array:

```
'tinymce'       => array(
            'toolbar1'      => $b,
            'toolbar2'      => '',
            'toolbar3'      => '',
        )
```

Where $b is all buttons that I need (included hr and charmap). See:
 [Wordpress Developers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/#comment-2058)

Answer (score 0):

Before you can load the toolbar buttons you need to load the plugins:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/hr/
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/charmap/

You first need to see if the TinyMCE embedded in your WP version includes these plugins (they are in a standard WordPress setup).  You then need to add these plugins to the list of loaded plugins.  Once they are loaded adding the buttons to the toolbar will work.

I don't know anything about `teenymce` but (as an example) this is how TinyMCE Advanced loads extra plugins via a WordPress hook:

```
 add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', array( $this, 'tiny_mce_plugins' ), 999 );
```

*(The array is a list of plugin folder names)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if your solution works. I solved in other way. See above my updated question!